# SQL get one row for each table_number filtered by lastest date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get one row for each table_number filtered by lastest date.

And if possible how can I do it with JPA ,I am using spring boot.

```
order_table_id date                        is_done is_started table_number
-------------- --------------------------- ------- ---------- ------------
2              2019-11-15 21:01:51.1266667 0       1          1
3              2019-11-15 21:02:32.4166667 0       1          2
4              2019-11-15 21:02:39.1333333 0       0          3
5              2019-11-15 21:02:46.2200000 1       1          4
10             2019-11-16 21:02:46.2200000 1       0          4
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please **attempt something** then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please indicate what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, a convenient method is `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on(table_number) t.*
from mytable t
order by t.table_number, t.date desc, order_table_id desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f2f2f9e256d753459e9ba8a142fa08f)**:

```
order_table_id | date                | is_done_is_ | started | table_number
-------------: | :------------------ | ----------: | ------: | -----------:
             2 | 2019-11-15 21:01:51 |           0 |       1 |            1
             3 | 2019-11-15 21:02:32 |           0 |       1 |            2
             4 | 2019-11-15 21:02:39 |           0 |       0 |            3
            10 | 2019-11-16 21:02:46 |           1 |       0 |            4
```

NB: your sample data does not really make sense, since both records belonging to `table_number` `4` have the same `date`. I added an addition sorting criteria to break the tie in a consistant manner.

---

In RDBMS that support window functions (such as SQL Server), one method is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() 
            over(partition by table_number order by date desc, order_table_id desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I am using SQL server,with your query i am getting error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'."

Comment: @VjekoslavKrainovic: So why did you tag your question `postgresql`?

Comment: Day in the date is different,but your solution works now,thank you alot!